# how can we use js to get hidden value in loop table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the list and loop it in table, and I have table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
   <td>Hidenfield</td>
   <td>Dropdownlist</td>
 </tr>
//loop here and have result
  <tr>
    <td><input type='hiden' value='1' class='myclass'/></td>
    <td>
       <select id="cateActive" class="activeStatus" name="cateActive">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Deactive</option>
       </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='hiden' value='2' class='myclass'/></td>
    <td>
       <select id="cateActive" class="activeStatus" name="cateActive">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Deactive</option>
       </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='hiden' value='3' class='myclass'/></td>
    <td>
       <select id="cateActive" class="activeStatus" name="cateActive">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Deactive</option>
       </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I have a jquery function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".activeStatus").change(function(){

         var categoryId = $('.myclass').val();
         alert(categoryId);

 });
});
```

when I click in any dropdownlist it has show the value is 1, how can I action on any dropdownbox to get hidden value in row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var categoryId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.myclass').val();
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7qp5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".activeStatus").change(function(){
        var categoryId = $(this).parent().prev().find('.myclass').val();
        alert(categoryId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Y8r8K/)

use delegate as you adding rows on run time and select particular row element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
  $(".activeStatus").on('change',function(){    
      var categoryId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.myclass').val();
      alert(categoryId);    
  });
});
```

Comment: glad you got the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('.myclass')`returns an array with more than one elements and the plain call of `.val()`returns always the value from first elment. So you have to iterate throught the array -here `categoryId` is your result array (or list).